# Cross Compile Android (Mako) Kernel with Linaro Toolchain

Tags: android, kernel, toolchain, linaro

i successfully compiled and boot my own kernel with this tips:

http://astro.temple.edu/~tue68607/project/articles/customized-android-aospsystem-nexus4.html

so now I wanted to use Linaro toolchain.

I tested setting path with the Google's method but can't work. I got this error

```
najmi@raden-aufa-qistina:~/android/kernel/msm$ export ARCH=arm
najmi@raden-aufa-qistina:~/android/kernel/msm$ export SUBARCH=arm
najmi@raden-aufa-qistina:~/android/kernel/msm$ export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-androideabi-
najmi@raden-aufa-qistina:~/android/kernel/msm$ make mako_defconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
warning: (ARCH_MSM_KRAITMP && ARCH_MSM_CORTEX_A5) selects HAVE_HW_BRKPT_RESERVED_RW_ACCESS which has unmet direct dependencies (HAVE_HW_BREAKPOINT)
warning: (ARCH_MSM_KRAITMP && ARCH_MSM_CORTEX_A5) selects HAVE_HW_BRKPT_RESERVED_RW_ACCESS which has unmet direct dependencies (HAVE_HW_BREAKPOINT)
#
# configuration written to .config
#
najmi@raden-aufa-qistina:~/android/kernel/msm$ make -j8
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
warning: (ARCH_MSM_KRAITMP && ARCH_MSM_CORTEX_A5) selects HAVE_HW_BRKPT_RESERVED_RW_ACCESS which has unmet direct dependencies (HAVE_HW_BREAKPOINT)
warning: (ARCH_MSM_KRAITMP && ARCH_MSM_CORTEX_A5) selects HAVE_HW_BRKPT_RESERVED_RW_ACCESS which has unmet direct dependencies (HAVE_HW_BREAKPOINT)
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/conmakehash
  HOSTCC  scripts/kallsyms
  HOSTCC  scripts/bin2c
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/mk_elfconfig
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
Is your PATH set correctly?
make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  HOSTCC  scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders
  HOSTCC  scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp
make[1]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I already set the path correct to point here:

```
/home/najmi/android/toolchain/linaro-git/android-toolchain-eabi/arm-linux-androideabi/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, as the error said

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
```

This means that the current version of NDK that your are using dose not conatin gcc. So,try an older version of android NDK(I suggest version 15c which contains gcc).
https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html

Then, try the following in the same order :

```
$ export ARCH=arm
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=<your path >/android-ndk-r15c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
$ make mako_defconfig
$ make -j4
```

make sure to run the following code to clean any previous compilation before running compile anything. if you didn't compile anything. then no need to run this code

```
$ make clean && make mrproper
```

I've tested before and its work.