# Build error: Missing toolchain in PATH?

Tags: android, linux, path, kernel, toolchain

I have a problem while compiling a ROM:

> ccache: FATAL: Could not find compiler "arm-eabigcc" in PATH

And my .bashrc where I set my Toolchains is set this way:

```
Android Toolchains PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/home/slimshadys/SlimMM/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-uber-4.9/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/home/slimshadys/SlimMM/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-uber/bin
```

The toolchains are in the right directory and I also set them into BoardConfig.mk in the right way.. Maybe the problem could be that it is looking for arm-eabigcc and not for arm-eabi-gcc .. How can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like `CROSS_COMPILE` variable is incorrectly set to `arm-eabi`. It should be `arm-eabi-` (with tailing dash).

Comment: Where can I find cross_compile variable?

Comment: `grep` scripts.. or googling. You can also set it manually, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186572/cross-compile-android-mako-kernel-with-linaro-toolchain).

Comment: If I want to add it manually, do I have to add it to .bashrc? If yes, I already have it.

Comment: If globally set variable doesn't help, then it is reseted somewhere in toolchain, seach it there.